# Two Records of same model with different values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey guys I'm currently developing a part in my app where a devise user is able to fill out a form with past work experience and education. I am using nested attributes to create a record for work experience and education which works fine. But I want to be able to add more than one work experience and more than one education in the same form

I've tried to use nested attributes and tried to create 2 record when the form is submitted the records are created but have the same values for employer

**user.rb**

```
   has_many :work_exps
   has_many :educations   
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :work_exps
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :educations
```

**experience.html.erb**

```
 <%= form_for :user, url: 'experience'  do  |f|%>
   <h3>work experience:</h3>
   <%= fields_for :work_exps do |u| %>
     <%= u.label :employer %><br />
     <%= u.text_field :employer %><br>
     <%= u.label :employer %><br />
     <%= u.text_field :employer %>
  <% end %>
  <%= fields_for :educations do |u| %>
    <%= u.label :school %><br />
    <%= u.text_field :school %>
  <% end %>
```

**routes**

```
 post 'care_giver_steps/experience', to: 'care_giver_steps#experience'
```

**controller**

```
def new
  @user = current_user
  @user.work_exps.build 
  @user.educations.build
  render_wizard
end

def experience
  @user = current_user 
  2.times{@user.work_exps.create(sanitize_work)}
  @user.educations.create(sanitize_education) 
  redirect_to team_root_path       
end


private 
  def sanitize_work
     params.require(:work_exps).permit(:employer,:title)
  end
  def sanitize_education
     params.require(:educations).permit(:major,:school)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def new
      @user = current_user
      2.times{@user.work_exps.build}
      @user.educations.build
      render_wizard
    end

    def experience
      @user = current_user 
      @user.update(sanitize_params) 
      redirect_to team_root_path       
    end
private 
  def sanitize_params
     params.require(:user).permit(work_exps_attributes: [:employer,:title], educations_attributes: [:major,:school])
  end
```

routes.rb

```
 post 'care_giver_steps/experience', to: 'care_giver_steps#experience', as: :care_giver_steps_experience
```

experince.html.erb

```
 <%= form_for :user, url: care_giver_steps_experience_path  do  |f|%>
   <h3>work experience:</h3>
   <%= fields_for :work_exps do |u| %>
     <%= u.label :employer %><br />
     <%= u.text_field :employer %><br>
     <%= u.label :employer %><br />
     <%= u.text_field :employer %>
  <% end %>
  <%= fields_for :educations do |u| %>
    <%= u.label :school %><br />
    <%= u.text_field :school %>
  <% end %>
```

Reference - [Ruby on Rails Nested Attributes](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes)

Comment: all i have to do is comment out where im creating the record ?

Comment: @kevinlopez Not so, you should build two nested form for `work_exps` to create two records. i.e `2.times{@user.work_exps.build}`

Comment: thanks for quick reply i have adjusted the code and now no records are being written to my DB

Comment: Can we talk through chat please?

Comment: @kevinlopez You can have a look at the modified answer for nested attributes form.

Comment: @kevinlopez What's your gmail?

Comment: lopezkevin175@gmail.com